Working with MODBUS RTU to read holding registers from a WAGO Power Measurement Module
I am attempting to create a GUI to communicate with a WAGO 3-Phase Power Measurement Module (Item No. 2857-570/024-005) to read measured values and change measurement parameters (referred to as WAGO from here on out). This WAGO communicates via MODBUS RTU, and due to requirements and restrictions from my employer I am unable to use a PLC and must communicate to the WAGO directly from my windows PC, additionally, for the same reasons I am unable to use a program called CODESYS that WAGO themselves recommend for MODBUS communication with their device. In order to get around this I have written up a program using Visual Studio (in C#) using the NModbus4 package to communicate with my WAGO module. However, upon running my program, I do not get a response from the WAGO when trying to read a simple holding register.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO.Ports;

using Modbus.Data;
using Modbus.Device;
using Modbus.Utility;
using Modbus.Message;
using Modbus.IO; 
//using Modbus.Serial;



namespace MODBUS_RTU_Tester
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Specify the COM port assigned to the RS-485 Adapter
            string comPort = "COM4"; //Replace with your desired COM port
            int baudRate = 19200; // Standard MODBUS baud rate
            Parity parity = Parity.Even; //Ensure it matches your devices configuration
            int dataBits = 8; //Standard for MODBUS
            StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One;
            Console.WriteLine("MODBUS RTU Tester");

            using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort(comPort))
            {
                port.BaudRate = baudRate;
                port.Parity = parity;
                port.DataBits = dataBits;
                port.StopBits = stopBits;
                port.ReadTimeout = 5000; //Timeout adjustments
                port.WriteTimeout = 5000;
                //port.Open(); //Open the port for communication

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Opening serial port...");
                    port.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Serial port opened successfully");

                    IModbusSerialMaster modbusMaster = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port);


                    byte slaveAddress = 7; //WAGO module address
                    ushort startAddress = 0; //Register Address
                    ushort numberOfRegisters = 1; //Number of Registers
                    Console.WriteLine("Reading holding registers");
                    ushort[] registers;

                    try
                    {
                        //Read holding registers
                        registers = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveAddress, startAddress, numberOfRegisters);

                        Console.WriteLine("Register Values:");
                        for (int i = 0; i < registers.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Register {startAddress + i}: {registers[i]}");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error reading registers: {ex.Message}");
                        return;
                    }


                    //Write to a single register
                    ushort registerToWrite = 0x0054;
                    ushort valueToWrite = 440;

                    try
                    {
                        modbusMaster.WriteSingleRegister(slaveAddress, registerToWrite, valueToWrite);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Wrote value {valueToWrite} to register {registerToWrite}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error writing registers: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                }                
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Closing serial port...");
                    if (port.IsOpen) port.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("Serial port closed.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                
            }
        }
    }
}


For context, I am using a MOXA UPort 1130 USB-to-Serial Adapter configured for RS-485 2-wire at 19200 baud, even parity, 8 data bits, and one stop bit, as well as the correct drivers. I have also configured the WAGO to have a slave address of 7, 19200 baud, even parity, 8 data bits, and one stop bit. Additionally, I have the WAGO connected to the UPort 1130 via a CAT 7 shielded twisted pair cable with wire 4 connected to the D+ terminal and wire 5 connected to the D- terminal of the UPort 1130, I also have the GND wire connected as well, per the suggestion from the WAGO's manual.
I have tried setting and using different slave addresses, tried 9600 baud, reading from different starting registers (using hex and decimal), and different parities with no success from any of these. Additionally I have used a scope/logic analyzer to view the signals being sent from and received by my PC and I verified that my request from the PC was correct, but there was no response from the WAGO after multiple attempts. I was told I should not need termination resistors or even a ground wire after having a few other engineers at my company try and help me out. I am new to working with MODBUS and so I wouldn't be surprised if I was missing something trivial that is causing this, but I have exhausted every possible avenue for a solution that I could come up with.
Can anyone help me diagnose this problem and propose a potential solution? I am pretty much out of options on what to try next at this point and I can't find anything on this website that helped me solve this problem. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: After doing some more digging and speaking to coworkers I found out that my MOXA UPort 1130 was main issue. I was using a faulty device and was able to figure that out after I found another usb-rs485 cable I had laying around. At the beginning I was sceptical about the MOXA UPort 1130, but I was told that it was working fine and I did not need to verify that. I was able to communicate with the WAGO module using the FieldTalk Modbus driver in my power shell. However, the code I have written still does not work properly and it cannot read a holding register on the WAGO. Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this?

It appears that NModbus is a fork of NModbus4 that is actively supported.

Have you used some third party software to verify that all the hardware is working as intended? We mostly use RMMS for modbus testing.

@JonasH I have been unable to do so at the moment. IT at my company is quite restrictive and all software goes through a lengthy review process before it can be installed (we can't even change the baud rate of our COM ports without them doing it). IT is currently in the process of approving QModMaster for use to verify if everything is working as intended. But if you specifically recommend RMMS I will start the approval process for that as well.

I'm hardly an expert in the area, but RMMS have worked well enough for our modest use cases. I suspect QModMaster would work just as well. But being able to test different parts of the system in isolation is super useful.

@Itallmakescents I am seeing that now. When I first started on this the description of NModbus4 made me think it was a fork of NModbus, not the other way around. I am currently writing a new version of my program with the NModbus package and I will post it here once I am finished.
